# Что возвращает sizeof() при применении к std::array?

Tags: c++, stl, стандарт, sizeof

Скажите, пожалуйста, что `Стандарт C++` говорит про следующий код:

```
std::array<char, 10> arr;
memset(arr.data(), 0, sizeof(arr));
```

У меня есть некоторые сомнения в том, что:

```
sizeof(arr) == sizeof(char) * arr.size()
```

Comment: не дадите ссылочку на стандарт с++ где такое написано?

Comment: Почему бы заглянуть в стандарт самостоятельно и задать вопрос только если что-то непонятно?

Comment: Я не уверен, что конкретно такое написано в `Стандарте`, я лишь хочу понять, есть ли там прямое или косвенное подтверждение/опровержение указанного предположения.

Comment: [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) - это структура, там есть множество различных данных

Comment: @TigerTV.ru  и что с этого?

Comment: Ну так сначала надо было прочитать, что там написано, а же потом спрашивать, если вопрос про косвенное подтверждение/опровержение не прояснился.

Comment: @MGNeo не уверены, но при этом такое пишите - это странно. Не знаю что действительно написано в стандарте по поводу std::array но это явно плохая идея: у этого класса есть специальные методы для получения размера - ими и следует пользоваться

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, c того, что размeр std::array зависит не только от полезных данных, но и от служебных.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru , не считаете, что лучше, когда  поясняете до конца? Случайный пользователь или ТС не обязательно могут понять вас, а теперь все предельно понятно....

Comment: По моему вопрос не имеет практического применения, и пользователям не нужно знать  внутренности.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, внутренности полезно знать, особенно если язык может работать на низком уровне. Если, что-то не понятно можно спросить. Что в принципе и произошло.)

Comment: Так как `array` это структура, её размер почти всегда больше `sizeof(arr) >= sizeof(char) * arr.size()` из-за выравнивания памяти. А при обнулении всей структуры вы можете испортить внутреннюю информацию (размеры) или выйдете за пределы структуры.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, как хотите. Водитель может и не знать внутреннее устройство своей машины, но ему гораздо проще если он знает когда возникают неполадки, да и когда эксплуатирует машину ему проще.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильнее

```
std::array<char, 10> arr;
memset(arr.data(), 0, arr.size()*sizeof(char));
```

Потому что хотя реально в ряде реализаций `sizeof(arr)` и соответствует размеру памяти для массива (например, в VC++ 2019), это, насколько мне известно, не гарантируется... А вот о `arr.size()` говорится прямо и недвусмысленно.

Comment: Странно, вопрос вроде про то, что говорит стандарт, а не про то, что вам известно. Могли бы хотя бы привести источник, откуда это вам стало известно.

Comment: @user7860670, предполагаю, что стандарт явно ничего не говорит о соотношении размера `std::array` и хранящихся в нём данных. Вероятно, из того факта, что `std::array` есть [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), следует, что размер экземпляра `std::array` не меньше, чем размер подлежащего массива, но никак не следует, что не больше...

Comment: [Is the size of `std::array` defined by standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19103244)

Comment: @user7860670 Из стандарта - там нет ничего ни слова о `sizeof(std::array)`. Какие еще нужны источники?